# Convergence with respect to the sup norm of the sequence $f_n(x) = x^{n+1} - x^n$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to determine whether the sequence $f_n(x)=x^{n+1}-x^n$ converges in $C([0,1])$ with respect to the supremum norm, $||f||=\sup\{|f(x)|\,:\,x\in S\}$, where $f$ is defined on the set $S$, and if it is convergent find it's limit.

I have proved that $f_n(x)=x^n$ is not convergent as it is not Cauchy, but I am unsure of how to proceed for this sequence.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Finding the minimum and maximum of $f_n$ helps. How would you find them?

Comment: Do you know the limit of your sequence?

Comment: @science I think it's $0$, as for $n \to \infty$ the distance between $x^n$, $x^{n+1}$ is negligible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an idea for what the limit could be, first calculate $x^{n+1} - x^n \to 0-0= 0$ for $x\in (0,1)$ and $x^{n+1} - x^n =1-1= 0$ for $x=1$. Hence, the limit function is $0$, we just have to check for uniform convergence.

When you considered the sequence $x^n$, you probably noted that the convergence **is** uniform on $[0,1-\varepsilon]$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$, but not on the whole interval.

The idea here is that $x^{n+1} - x^n = x^n (x-1)$ and the factor $x-1$ is small (in absolute value) for $x \in [1-\varepsilon, 1]$.

**I suggest that you take these ideas to derive the proof yourself. If you get stuck, look at the rest of this answer.**

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary. For $x\in\left[0,1\right]$, there
are two cases:

1. We have $x\in\left[0,1-\varepsilon\right]$. Then
   $$
   \left|x^{n-1}-x^{n}\right|=\left|x^{n}\left(1-x\right)\right|\leq\left|x^{n}\right|\leq\left(1-\varepsilon\right)^{n}.
   $$
2. We have $x\in\left[1-\varepsilon,1\right]$. Then
   $$
   \left|x^{n-1}-x^{n}\right|=\left|x^{n}\left(1-x\right)\right|\leq\left|1-x\right|=1-x\leq1-\left(1-\varepsilon\right)=\varepsilon.
   $$

All in all, we conclude
$$
\left\Vert x^{n+1}-x^{n}\right\Vert _{\sup}\leq\max\left\{ \varepsilon,\left(1-\varepsilon\right)^{n}\right\} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\varepsilon
$$
and thus
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left\Vert x^{n+1}-x^{n}\right\Vert _{\sup}\leq\varepsilon
$$
for all $\varepsilon>0$. This yields $\left\Vert x^{n+1}-x^{n}\right\Vert _{\sup}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$,
so that your sequence converges uniformly to $0$.

Comment: I'm confused about the factoring of $x^{n+1}-x^n$.  I'm finding that $x^{n+1}-x^n=x^nx^1-x^n=x^n(x-1)$

Comment: @jdhw: Oh, yes, you are right. But multiplying everything by $-1$ does not change the rest (especially since we are only interested in the absolute value).

Answer (score 1):

You can see that the limit of the sequence is $0$. So we have

$$ \sup_{0\leq x \leq 1}\bigg|x^n-x^{n+1} -0\bigg| \leq \frac{\left( \frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n }{n+1}< \frac{1}{n+1}< \epsilon.  $$

You can find the sup by using the derivative test to the function $x^n-x^{n+1}$.

Comment: Would you find sharing how you got  $\sup_{0\leq x \leq 1}\bigg|x^n-x^{n+1} -0\bigg| \leq \frac{\left( \frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n }{n+1}< \frac{1}{n+1}$?  I find that when I take the derivative and set it to $0$ I get that $x=\frac{n}{n+1}$, but I'm unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: @jdhw: Check the second derivative of the function $f_n(x)=x^{n}-x^{n+1}$ at the point $x=\frac{n}{n+1}$ and you will find it is negative which means it is a maxima. Then evaluate the function at this point $f_n(\frac{n}{n+1})$.